# How do I file a bug or feature request about github.com---as in THE github?

Tags: github, issue-tracking

I found a minor bug-like behavior in the GitHub interface. Or maybe what I am really after is a new or improved feature.

Is there a public GitHub repo for the GitHub code base? Or, where is the appropriate place to file this issue?

Any web search with terms like "GitHub" along with "issue" or "bug" inevitably leads to instructions for how to file GitHub issues or submit feature requests for GitHub repos in general. There is too much noise to find results about the GitHub itself.

Comment: Did you try searching **on** Github? Or just... going to github dot com and scrolling down to the page footer and seeing if anything in there looked interesting?

Answer (score 6):

I finally found it. I hadn't thought of looking searching for "bug in GitHub website." Adding "website" led me to GitHub support.

https://support.github.com/request

Feature requests go to the [discussion board](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions). Bug reports go [here](https://support.github.com/contact/bug-report)